# What is the meaning of svg:svg?

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, d3.js

What is the meaning of this?

```
.append("svg:svg")
```

I saw it in HTML and in D3 code. Does it add plugin of SVG?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In XHTML code, one can use namespaces to distinguish other XML-based languages included in the webpage. Here, the namespace "svg" is used before the tag "svg".

```
namespace:tagname
```

This can be useful in case two tags (for example, in XHTML and SVG) have the same name and you want to exactly specify which one you refer to. The tags can be specified with the `xmlns` attribute. As you know, XHTML documents start with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

you may specify the prefix as

```
<html xmlns:prefix="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and then you'll use

```
<prefix:head>
    <prefix:title></prefix:title>
</prefix:head>
```

Similarily you can use

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

instead of just `<svg>` when including your svg graphic. Then all svg tags will start with the `svgprefix` prefix. However if you have child SVG nodes, they will also need this `xmlns` attribute to be defined. In such a case, defining the prefix will probably be easier.

Comment: Downvoted; although this information is correct and related, the OP's question is related to a JavaScript string with specific application in D3.js, not XML markup.

Comment: @Phrogz I respectfully disagree. The question is posed: "what is svg:svg?" and I answered exactly that question, what resulted in this answer being accepted. Op says they saw it in D3 and HTML code, not just D3 as you imply. It seems to me that op is aware that `append` functions gets a tagname, only didn't know what kind of tagname `svg:svg` is, guessing it to be a SVG plugin. You can't say this is a JS issue either, as the question was not tagged `JavaScript`.

Comment: I respect your respectful disagreement. :) To me the code in question `.append("svg:svg")` along with a mention of D3.js makes it clearly a coding question. However, given your good point about seeing it "in HTML" I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 16):

From the documentation for [D3.js's `append()` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append):

> *The element's tag name may have a namespace prefix, such as "svg:text" to create a "text" element in the SVG namespace. By default, D3 supports svg, xhtml, xlink, xml and xmlns namespaces. Additional namespaces can be registered by adding to [`d3.ns.prefix`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Namespaces#wiki-prefix).*

**Note in particular that the namespace prefixes in D3.js are *not* based on your document, but a predefined map of common prefixes to the actual namespace URL.**

Namespaces are the way an XML document (which includes XHTML **but not HTML**) can include two attributes or elements with the same name (e.g. "sin" as in mathematical sine calculation vs. "sin" as in moral failing) without conflict. Putting an `<svg>` element in an XHTML document has no meaning unless that SVG element is in the [SVG namespace](http://www.w3.org/2000/svg).

For more information, read [Namespaces in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

Comment: Just for the record, namespacing is optional in d3 since Nov 23, 2011