# Difference between js syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

what are the differences in syntax between

```
.append("svg")
```

vs.

```
.append("svg:svg")
```

what are the pros and cons and what do they imply?

I am using jQuery and D3

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this is tagged as 'css'

Comment: @gmeben I wasn't entirely sure it was js related or if that was a way of addressing css selectors

Comment: .append is a method in jQuery. This has nothing to do with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both does same function *append*

In XHTML code, one can use namespaces to distinguish other XML-based languages included in the webpage. Here, the namespace "svg" is used before the tag "svg".

```
namespace:tagname
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583400/what-is-the-meaning-of-svgsvg)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a difference in Javascript syntax. One is appending an svg element, the other is appending a namespaced svg element.